# STS IDE, Maven, Google Guava

Tags: java, spring, guava

I'm trying to download the latest version of Google Guava via Spring's STS IDE and Maven. When I click add and search for the artifact Id: "guava" I only get the result for version 11 (see below). Version 13 is the latest version. Any ideas what's going on?

[image]

Comment: have you confirmed that the version you want is actually in the repository you are connected to? there are many web interfaces that will let you browse these public repos

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I'm not for sure what you mean. I hope the pom.xml file in STS and click the Add button and all I do is search. I'm not for certain where it connects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the Global repository in the Maven Repositories view and click Full Index Enabled (warning: slow).

Or, just enter the new version number by hand. It will search for and download the jar as part of the next build.

Comment: Thanks. I will just enter it by hand, but can you tell me what the Global repository is or where it is located?

Comment: It's in the Maven Repositories view (press Ctrl-3, then start typing 'Maven Repositories')

Answer (score 0):

Probably Eclipse needs to update Maven indexes.

Comment: So is my only option to download the jar file and import?